In MacOS, how do you use the Signet symbol of the Live Speech window?
I am trying to use Live Speech to easily dictate things repeatedly instead of having to say them
I see a signet icon at the right of the Live Speech window, but I cannot understand how to use it. When I click it, it does nothing and the sentences disappear after having been spoken by the computer.

Can one bookmark their Live Speech items for future reuse? How does it work?
